# Analysis, Density of Rational Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, rational-numbers

Suppose $p/q$ and $k/l$ are rational numbers with $\left|(p/q - k/l)\right|< {1}/{ql}$.  Prove $p/q = k/l$.

Similarly, let $p/q$ be a fixed rational number and suppose $k/l$ is a rational number with $0 < \left|p/q - k/l \right| < 1/qm$ ... for some natural number m.  Show that $m < l$.

The work I've done with these is just algebra to split up the absolute value inequalities but I can't logically work out the problems.  I'd prefer tips over a complete answer to the problem as these are for homework.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $pl-qk \in \mathbb{Z}$.

> $a \in \mathbb{Z},\ |a|<1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a = 0$.

Comment: In the second problem I separate the inequality and get pl < qk or qk < pl and on the other side m(pl - qk) < l and m(qk - pl) < l.  I can't figure out where to go from here.  I did solve the first problem.

Comment: $pl \ne qk$, so $|pl-qk| \ge 1$. Hence $\left|\frac{p}{q} - \frac{k}{l}\right| \ge \frac{1}{ql}$.